# jQuery slide in from outside the screen and IE ofverflow issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, overflow

I needed a div to slide in from beyond right edge of the screen.
So I defined the CSS:

```
#mydiv {
position: relative;
left: 2000px;
}
and to prevent scrollbars:
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Then in jQuery:

```
$("#mydiv").animate({"left":"-=2000px"},1500);
```

This solution worked just OK in FF and Chrome but than I found out 
overflow-x: hidden
doesn't work in IE and all the object I want to slide in are visible.
Does anyone know some solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your `#mydiv` in another div that is `width:100%` and `overflow:hidden` maybe?